# Select Into trigger linked to Update command in MSSQL changes the return value of the affected rows - How to avoid this?

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, ado.net

We are using Ado library in MS Visual C++ to use MS SQL database in the following way:

```
_CommandPtr pCmd;

...
            pCmd->CommandText      = “update …”;

            pCmd->Execute( &lRowsAffected, 0, adExecuteNoRecords  );
```

After executing the update command, the lRowsAffected variable gives us the number of affected rows, which is exactly what we want. However, if in MS SQL a trigger starting with a `select into` command is defined for the update command, we get the number of rows selected by the `select into` command as the value of lRowsAffected. Instead of this, we would like to know how many rows were affected by the update command, how could we achieve this?

Comment: At the beginning of the trigger body put [set nocount on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259204%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this has solved our problem!